# Binning in r with actual & Error Percentages

Tags: r, boxplot, binning

I have a data set where I have my actual sales & error percentages (calculated using the predicted values of the sales):

```
Sales   Error%
1   923.4321722
2   97.3662199
2   1509.473683
2   33.06024198
2   62.69180031
3   258.0317619
3   89.27191866
3   89.27191866
3   21.68605698
3   11.05611111
3   119.5560393
```

I want to bin the sales & create a box plot with the binned numbers as my x label & error% as y label.

Can any one help me with at least the binning procedure?

Comment: you mean `boxplot(df$Error ~ df$Sales)` ?

Comment: Box plot is fine but how do I bin the sales so as to have the error% in the y axis?

Comment: Bin the numbers to what?  `Error%` is already the y-axis.

Comment: What exactly doyou mean by binning? Do you want to group the values of Error% somehow?

Comment: I want something like this                                                                                           1-10                      11-20
0.010919048 0.019600549
0.277365873 0.052173993
0.306005051 0.086288889
0.331807143 0.0966
& have the box plot where x will have values 1-10 & Y the errors

Comment: perhaps `?.bincode`

Comment: can you post all your data